# Error kernel Out of memory: Killed process (uwsgi) & consume too much memory

Tags: django, linux, memory-leaks, uwsgi

In the past few days, my site is crashing and OS message logs shows the OOM killer kills the process.

Server have 32GB RAM but still we face **Out Of Memory** Issue due to uwsgi.

OS: Gentoo Linux

Here is my uwsgi.ini

```
[uwsgi]
chdir = /var/www/%n
virtualenv = venv
pythonpath = %(chdir)/python/
socket = /var/run/uwsgi/%n.sock
logger = syslog:%n
vacuum = true
module = mysite.wsgi:application
master = true
threads = 32
enable-threads = true
plugins = python27
spooler = %(chdir)/uwsgi_spooler
spooler-processes = 5
spooler-frequency = 5
import = mysite.fork
env = LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8
env = LANG=en_us.UTF-8
```

Error Message logs

```
/var/log/messages:Jul 20 06:31:39 ip-10-0-0-45 kernel: Out of memory: Killed process 16625 (uwsgi) total-vm:6933540kB, anon-rss:1988220kB, file-rss:3676kB, shmem-rss:68kB, UID:998 pgtables:12824kB oom_score_adj:0
/var/log/messages:Jul 20 16:02:48 ip-10-0-0-45 kernel: Out of memory: Killed process 25622 (uwsgi) total-vm:8216796kB, anon-rss:3184288kB, file-rss:4336kB, shmem-rss:72kB, UID:998 pgtables:15408kB oom_score_adj:0
/var/log/messages:Jul 20 18:22:25 ip-10-0-0-45 kernel: Out of memory: Killed process 27520 (uwsgi) total-vm:10033820kB, anon-rss:7766404kB, file-rss:4900kB, shmem-rss:72kB, UID:998 pgtables:18960kB oom_score_adj:0
/var/log/messages:Jul 20 18:41:47 ip-10-0-0-45 kernel: Out of memory: Killed process 26553 (uwsgi) total-vm:9450820kB, anon-rss:4271912kB, file-rss:0kB, shmem-rss:408kB, UID:998 pgtables:15804kB oom_score_adj:0
/var/log/messages:Jul 20 18:43:58 ip-10-0-0-45 kernel: Out of memory: Killed process 26988 (uwsgi) total-vm:9023384kB, anon-rss:4560056kB, file-rss:4896kB, shmem-rss:40kB, UID:998 pgtables:17080kB oom_score_adj:0
/var/log/messages:Jul 20 18:49:20 ip-10-0-0-45 kernel: Out of memory: Killed process 21873 (uwsgi) total-vm:9285132kB, anon-rss:3033004kB, file-rss:4832kB, shmem-rss:72kB, UID:998 pgtables:14568kB oom_score_adj:0
/var/log/messages:Jul 20 18:51:34 ip-10-0-0-45 kernel: Out of memory: Killed process 29571 (uwsgi) total-vm:6444336kB, anon-rss:1227940kB, file-rss:3936kB, shmem-rss:48kB, UID:998 pgtables:12192kB oom_score_adj:0
/var/log/messages:Jul 20 18:56:26 ip-10-0-0-45 kernel: Out of memory: Killed process 30172 (uwsgi) total-vm:10266664kB, anon-rss:5881624kB, file-rss:0kB, shmem-rss:128kB, UID:998 pgtables:15112kB oom_score_adj:0
/var/log/messages:Jul 20 18:59:25 ip-10-0-0-45 kernel: Out of memory: Killed process 30274 (uwsgi) total-vm:8246172kB, anon-rss:3425064kB, file-rss:4332kB, shmem-rss:24kB, UID:998 pgtables:14092kB oom_score_adj:0
/var/log/messages:Jul 20 19:03:30 ip-10-0-0-45 kernel: Out of memory: Killed process 30314 (uwsgi) total-vm:10782800kB, anon-rss:6666008kB, file-rss:4524kB, shmem-rss:24kB, UID:998 pgtables:18696kB oom_score_adj:0
/var/log/messages:Jul 20 19:06:50 ip-10-0-0-45 kernel: Out of memory: Killed process 28100 (uwsgi) total-vm:11235180kB, anon-rss:4895520kB, file-rss:4384kB, shmem-rss:72kB, UID:998 pgtables:19316kB oom_score_adj:0
/var/log/messages:Jul 20 19:11:36 ip-10-0-0-45 kernel: Out of memory: Killed process 30093 (uwsgi) total-vm:6293036kB, anon-rss:2439872kB, file-rss:4768kB, shmem-rss:72kB, UID:998 pgtables:11900kB oom_score_adj:0
/var/log/messages:Jul 20 19:15:24 ip-10-0-0-45 kernel: Out of memory: Killed process 30552 (uwsgi) total-vm:8593196kB, anon-rss:5089644kB, file-rss:4824kB, shmem-rss:32kB, UID:998 pgtables:14448kB oom_score_adj:0
/var/log/messages:Jul 20 19:17:35 ip-10-0-0-45 kernel: Out of memory: Killed process 30599 (uwsgi) total-vm:8656020kB, anon-rss:5878128kB, file-rss:4588kB, shmem-rss:32kB, UID:998 pgtables:13384kB oom_score_adj:0
/var/log/messages:Jul 20 19:25:13 ip-10-0-0-45 kernel: Out of memory: Killed process 30506 (uwsgi) total-vm:6259896kB, anon-rss:3202268kB, file-rss:4460kB, shmem-rss:24kB, UID:998 pgtables:11420kB oom_score_adj:0
/var/log/messages:Jul 20 19:47:58 ip-10-0-0-45 kernel: Out of memory: Killed process 4557 (uwsgi) total-vm:9130312kB, anon-rss:6535448kB, file-rss:4292kB, shmem-rss:48kB, UID:998 pgtables:17320kB oom_score_adj:0
/var/log/messages:Jul 20 22:20:01 ip-10-0-0-45 kernel: Out of memory: Killed process 4896 (uwsgi) total-vm:13248296kB, anon-rss:6748320kB, file-rss:4460kB, shmem-rss:88kB, UID:998 pgtables:25424kB oom_score_adj:0
/var/log/messages:Jul 21 18:00:58 ip-10-0-0-45 kernel: Out of memory: Killed process 6206 (uwsgi) total-vm:6823704kB, anon-rss:3321452kB, file-rss:4896kB, shmem-rss:88kB, UID:998 pgtables:12772kB oom_score_adj:0
/var/log/messages:Jul 21 19:07:56 ip-10-0-0-45 kernel: Out of memory: Killed process 6207 (uwsgi) total-vm:6061608kB, anon-rss:2101788kB, file-rss:4208kB, shmem-rss:88kB, UID:998 pgtables:11268kB oom_score_adj:0
/var/log/messages:Jul 21 20:06:57 ip-10-0-0-45 kernel: Out of memory: Killed process 6209 (uwsgi) total-vm:5881580kB, anon-rss:4200748kB, file-rss:4896kB, shmem-rss:72kB, UID:998 pgtables:10900kB oom_score_adj:0
/var/log/messages:Jul 21 21:14:18 ip-10-0-0-45 kernel: Out of memory: Killed process 6211 (uwsgi) total-vm:7569124kB, anon-rss:2978188kB, file-rss:2772kB, shmem-rss:396kB, UID:998 pgtables:12000kB oom_score_adj:0
/var/log/messages:Jul 21 21:16:39 ip-10-0-0-45 kernel: Out of memory: Killed process 8909 (uwsgi) total-vm:7548232kB, anon-rss:6601784kB, file-rss:4800kB, shmem-rss:72kB, UID:998 pgtables:14308kB oom_score_adj:0
/var/log/messages:Jul 21 21:18:55 ip-10-0-0-45 kernel: Out of memory: Killed process 6208 (uwsgi) total-vm:9059004kB, anon-rss:4436060kB, file-rss:4640kB, shmem-rss:72kB, UID:998 pgtables:17140kB oom_score_adj:0
/var/log/messages:Jul 21 21:22:27 ip-10-0-0-45 kernel: Out of memory: Killed process 6210 (uwsgi) total-vm:11301012kB, anon-rss:5626612kB, file-rss:4836kB, shmem-rss:72kB, UID:998 pgtables:21208kB oom_score_adj:0
/var/log/messages:Jul 21 22:59:28 ip-10-0-0-45 kernel: Out of memory: Killed process 9244 (uwsgi) total-vm:11133048kB, anon-rss:6334996kB, file-rss:4908kB, shmem-rss:72kB, UID:998 pgtables:21364kB oom_score_adj:0
/var/log/messages:Jul 23 06:57:58 ip-10-0-0-45 kernel: Out of memory: Killed process 27936 (uwsgi) total-vm:7728168kB, anon-rss:6061784kB, file-rss:4244kB, shmem-rss:88kB, UID:998 pgtables:14620kB oom_score_adj:0
```

Is there any wrong config in uwsgi.ini

Comment: How many people are using your site? You should probably log into the server and try to figure out how the memory is being split. It's possible there's something wrong with your INI, but it's likely somewhere else in your site.

Answer (score 0):

The uwsgi is missing the max-request, so it is continually using the same threads which could lead to memory exhaustion depending how the underlying application is working.

https://uwsgi-docs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/Options.html#max-requests

> **max-requests**
>
> argument: required_argument
>
> shortcut: -R
>
> parser: uwsgi_opt_set_64bit
>
> help: reload workers after the specified amount of managed requests